# php sort a multidimensional array alphabetical

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array that is created with this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($sub_results);$i++)
{
    $presenters = array(
        'first_name' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][1]['user_value'],
        'last_name' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][2]['user_value'],
        'preferred_name' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][8]['user_value'],
        'organisation' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][11]['user_value'],
        'portraitFile' => $portrait_file_path.$portrait,
        'Abstract1title' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][19]['user_value'],
        'Abstract1accepted' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][18]['user_value'],
        'Abstract1synopsis' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][22]['user_value'],
        'Abstract1format' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][26]['user_value'],
        'Abstract1coauthors' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][20]['user_value'],
        'Abstract2title' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][28]['user_value'],
        'Abstract2accepted' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][27]['user_value'],
        'Abstract2synopsis' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][31]['user_value'],
        'Abstract2format' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][30]['user_value'],
        'Abstract2coauthors' => $sub_results[$i]['data'][29]['user_value']
    );
}
```

I want to sort the resulting array alphabetically by last_name. How is this achieved?

With thanks in advance,
emrys

Comment: What resulting array? Your loop just keeps overwriting the same variable, it's not appending to an array. Did you mean to write `$presenters[] = `?

Comment: Anyway, the obvious answer is to use `usort`. Supply a comparison function that compares the last names.

Comment: If that isn't working for you, please show your code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/usort  Example #2

Comment: I answered your question below, using usort.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.  It's case-insensitive.  If you have any questions about how it works let me know.  Remember that `usort` accepts the array by reference, meaning that if you want to preserve the original array you will need to make a copy of it.

```
<?php
    usort($array,function($a,$b) {
        $comparison = strcasecmp($a['last_name'],$b['last_name']);
        if ($comparison == 0) return 0;
        return ($comparison < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    });
?>
```

Comment: Great thank you. Also Barmar for pointing out a very obvious flaw in my control loop.